# Craft CMS Freeform unable to override value of invisible/hidden field

Tags: craft3, plugin-freeform, solspace, freeform

In my control panel, I have a hidden field type with name 'Payment Amount' and handle name 'paymentAmount'. I am trying to modify its value to be the same as another field of the same form called 'Email' with handle name 'email', however, I cannot even modify its value to a set value as defined in my template:

```
{% set form = craft.freeform.form(formHandle, {
    submitClass: "btn btn-primary",
    returnUrl: "{{ siteUrl }}freeform-demo/bootstrap/{{ form.handle }}/{% if submission %}submissions/{{ submission.id }}/{% endif %}success",
    submissionToken: submissionToken|default(null),

}) %}

{% if form %}
{{ form.renderTag({
        overrideValues: {
            paymentAmount: "yes",
         }
        }
    }) }}
{% endif %}
```

In my submission results only the default value of my hidden field shows up (which is blank)

Any help on this would be much appreciated.